# Automatically generate new divisions and label it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a script that automatically creates divisions on a spreadsheet. It receives as a value the number of times it has to create the same category of division. Each division/label it's composed of a merge of 6 cells in the same line.
I'm trying to make it work by using `getLastRow` as a base of the placement of the label, but I can't make it work it out with the merge.

Basically what I'm doing is:

```
function resumo() {
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let resumo = ss.getSheetByName("Resumo");
  let numEntrada = resumo.getRange("c12").getValue();

 criaParcela(); 

 function criaParcela() {
   for (i = 0;i < numEntrada; i++){
     var fLine = resumo.getLastRow();
     var bcell = (fLine+1);
     var fcell = (fLine+6);
     resumo.getRange(fcell,1).setValue("Entrada");
     resumo.getRange(bcell,1,6,1).mergeVertically();
   }
 }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm not professional programmer.

Comment: How would you like your end result to look like? Essentially you just want to merge the cells in the `bcell,1,6,1` range?

Comment: I want it to take the entry number and create the same number of subsequent vertical divisions equally labeled with the range of 6 cells merged. With `resumo.getRange(fcell,1).setValue("Entrada")` I'm trying to set a new value as the last row to have a new reference point `getLastRow` for the loop, but every time it gets merged it dosen't work the way I intended.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that this is the end result you are looking for:**

[image: end result]

**You can try the below script:**

```
function doStuff() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheetResumo = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Resumo");
  let numEntrada = sheetResumo.getRange("C12").getValue();
  for (let i = 0; i < numEntrada; i++) {
    let lastRow = sheetResumo.getLastRow() + 1;
    sheetResumo.getRange(lastRow, i+1, 6, 1).mergeVertically();
    
  }
}
```

The most notable changes that have been done to your script are the following:

**+ using only one function;**

Apps Script does not accept a function within a function in the way you had tried to use it.

**+ `getRange` method is getting the proper parameters in order to perform the merge operation successfully;**

As you can see, the `i` index is needed if you want to merge the same cells `numEntrada` multiple times.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).